# Copilot suggestions still remain after i leave insert mode ( neovim )

Tags: neovim

I am using copilot in vim, everything is great but i have a problem. When in insert mode, the copilot automatically suggestion the hint ( gray colors ) but after i leave insert mode, the hint is still visible and it cause irritating. How could i config that the copilot will also remove the hint after i leave insert mode in vim
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERE5Y.png)

Here is the config what i have so far

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({ "InsertLeave" }, {
  callback = function()
    local copilotc = require("copilot")
    copilotc.remove_inlay_hints()
  end
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you are exiting insert mode with either <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, as opposed to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. This removes the suggestion text for me (neovim 0.7.2 and copilot.vim 1.7.0).

For reference, `:help i_CTRL-[`

```
                        *i_CTRL-[* *i_<Esc>*
<Esc> or CTRL-[ End insert or Replace mode, go back to Normal mode.  Finish
        abbreviation.
        Note: If your <Esc> key is hard to hit, try CTRL-[ instead.
                        *i_META* *i_ALT*
        ALT (|META|) acts like <Esc> if the chord is not mapped.
        For example <A-x> acts like <Esc>x if <A-x> does not have an
        insert-mode mapping.
                        *i_CTRL-C*
CTRL-C      Quit insert mode, go back to Normal mode.  Do not check for
        abbreviations.  Does not trigger the |InsertLeave| autocommand
        event.
```